# Launch a dialog from a webapp

Tags: webapps

I'd like to launch a config dialog (by example made in python in /usr/bin/mydialog) from a webapp Action.

Can I do that? Please, how?

Thanks in advance!

---

For @terdon question:

I'd like to add an Action QuickList which open a Config Dialog for my webapp. Then you could config autostart, Mobile/Desktop view, Enable notifications... Just a config dialog.

What webapp? This: https://launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram

What language is it written in? I'd like to launch a python app created with Glade + Python as my Gufw app.

What system is it running on? Ubuntu 14.04

What have you tried? Nothing, I'm lost. The API hasn't anything about this. I'm just asking :)

Comment: Again, we have no idea what you have set up and cannot help you unless you explain what you're doing. What webapp action? What is this webapp, what was it written in? Most importantly, **what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I get that! :) [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~costales/unity-webapps-telegram/trunk/files/30) is the code.

You can add a static QuickList for calling an external python app, which will read/write the Local Storage, which will read the webapp ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the kindness of a developer, I can give some information to my questions.

It should be available soon (launch a dialog).

Best regards!